# Neglecting terms in an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, inequality

Let's say I have the following relationship: $a \gg b^2$. This means, that in practice, I can approximate the equation:

$y = a + b^2 +c \approx a + c$, since $a + b^2 \approx a$.

Would the same be true for:

$y = a - b^2 + c$? I.e., given the first inequality above, does this imply that $a -b^2 \approx a$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make that approximation.

$$\text{If } \text{ } a>>b^2 \\\text{then }a \pm b^2 \approx a$$